# Trying to display time component ie hour and minute of a date

Tags: php, datetime

For eg, I have this code for my PHP calendar events application.

```
/**MySQL code to get the date*/
$get_Eventbyid_sql = "select event_title, event_shortdesc, event_start as fmt_date from
calendar_events where id=".$_GET['id'].";";
```

where event_start is my date/time fields.

So now I want to display its hour and minute components on the form.

for eg if event_start was **2012-03-25 02:30:00**

Then I oughta get 02 and 30 by using the following code below.

```
echo "<input type=text name=event_time_hh value='".date("h",$fmt_date)."'>";
echo "<input type=text name=event_time_mm value='".date("i",$fmt_date)."'>";
```

But the results were different.

date("h", $fmt_date) returns 12:
date("i", $fmt_date) returns 33;

Where do these numbers come from?  Where did I go so wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `date` needs to be a numeric *timestamp*, not a date string. Use:

```
date('h', strtotime($fmt_date))
```

Also, take care of that [**SQL INJECTION**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)!

Comment: I think colorful capslock is the right way to bring up SQL INJECTION (I wish we could get a sitewide style consensus on this, maybe get a feature to make the OP's browser play a menacing chord when the word comes on screen).

Comment: @deceze: Thanks.  That's so much helpful!  Glad to know there's a trivial approach for this simple query.  Cheers! :)